TypeScript Return Type Conflict with RxJS's combineLatest
I'm working with RxJS in a TypeScript project and attempting to use the combineLatest function. I've defined the following method:
myMethod(): Observable<{ one: string }> {
  return combineLatest({
    one: of('one'),
    two: of('two'),
  });
}

I expected this to cause a TypeScript compilation error because the return type of my method specifies Observable<{ one: string }>, but the combineLatest function returns an observable that includes both one and two properties, which doesn't match the method's return type.
Any explanation or guidance would be appreciated.

The typing getting lost because of Observable<T>. When I try to do the same without the observable, typescript works.
myMethod(): Observable<{ one: string }> {
  return of({
    one: 'one',
    two: 'two',
  });
}

Stackblitz

The solution for this is to simply just use the typing on the combine latest, which when implemented similar to the combine latest throws an error, about the missing property.
export interface MyMethodType {
  // [key: string]: Observable<string>;
  one: string;
  two: string;
}
type TypedCombineLatest = {
  [K in 'one']: {
    one: Observable<string>;
    two: Observable<string>;
  }[K];
};
...

...
myMethod(): Observable<MyMethodType> {
  return combineLatest<TypedCombineLatest>({
    one: of<string>('one'),
    two: of<string>('two'),
  });
}

Stackblitz Demo
